# Python OptionParser list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to use agrs option in my function as below.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option('-f', '--file', action="store", dest="file", help="data file")
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

    if options.file is not None:
        csv_file = options.file
    else:
        csv_file = 'data/dev-access.csv'

    predict(csv_file, args[0])
```

Here is my Predict Funciton

```
def predict(csv_file, log_entry):
    # Loading processed word dictionary into keras Tokenizer would be better
    dataframe = pandas.read_csv(csv_file, engine='python', quotechar='|', header=None)
    dataset = dataframe.values

    # Preprocess dataset
    X = dataset[:,0]
    for index, item in enumerate(X):
        reqJson = json.loads(item, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
        del reqJson['timestamp']
        del reqJson['headers']
        del reqJson['source']
        del reqJson['route']
        del reqJson['responsePayload']
        X[index] = json.dumps(reqJson, separators=(',', ':'))

    tokenizer = Tokenizer(filters='\t\n', char_level=True)
    tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X)
    seq = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([log_entry])
    max_log_length = 1024
    log_entry_processed = sequence.pad_sequences(seq, maxlen=max_log_length)

    model = load_model('securitai-lstm-model.h5')
    model.load_weights('securitai-lstm-weights.h5')
    model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
    prediction = model.predict(log_entry_processed)
    print (prediction[0])
```

When i run the file i got these error.

```
 File "c:\redict.py", line 50, in <module>
    predict(csv_file, args[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

args[0] goes to tokenizer.texts_to_sequences as a parameter

Comment: Can you show us the code of `predict` function ?

Comment: Side-note: `optparse` has been deprecated since Python 3.2; I'd *strongly* suggest switching to [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).

Comment: @shotgunner: The `predict` function doesn't matter, as long as it's written in Python (not an extension module). Since it's not an extension function, the fact that the error points to that line implies the error occurs on that line before the call is actually made, not within `predict`. Cemal: How are you running this at the command line?

Comment: @shotgunner I want to give some args into predict function. I know that the error not made within predict function :(

Comment: `predict` is not important. Only how you run this. Do you use an IDE? command line?